# custom paper size on the command line?

Tags: lilypond

I'm working with three different paper sizes, i.e. the same music formatted for different page sizes.  This works fine for established paper dimensions.

```
lilypond -dpaper-size=\"letter\" -o "outFile-L" sourceFile.ly
```

or

```
lilypond -dpaper-size=\"statement\" -o "outFile-S" sourceFile.ly
```

But I also use a paper size not available in the `paper.scm` file.  Here's the code I use.

```
#(set! paper-alist (cons '("booklet" . (cons (* 7.0 in) (* 8.5 in))) paper-alist))
#(set-default-paper-size "booklet")
```

I'd really prefer it if I didn't have to edit each file to turn on/off the "booklet" page sizing.  Unfortunately if I try specify "booklet" on the command line it errors because the compiler sees the command line option before it reads the definition in the code: `warning: Unknown paper size: booklet`

I can imagine two different solutions:

1) Add "booklet" to the `paper.scm` file, with the understanding that every time Lilypond is upgraded I'll have to re-do the edit.

2) Create a common file that all music files have to source, but there are different versions of the file in different sub-directories, and that sub-dir is directed from the command line.

```
lilypond --include="./bookletDir" -o "outFile-B" sourceFile.ly
```

Any other (better) suggestions?

Comment: Option 2 seems good. You could also write a shell script along the lines of `alias lilypondbooklet="lilypond --include="./bookletDir"`...